# VBA - runtime error 6. Overflow

Tags: vba, excel, overflow

This is a code that I am trying to fix. This is from an excel spreadsheet macro.

Ex. When I run the Tally Inspector macro and type in the name of the inspector, the macro is suppose to take in the data form each days of the week and then populate the table which I made. But when I run it, I get the runtime error 6. Overflow error.

The code:

```
Sub Tally Inspector()    
    Dim personName As String
    personName = InputBox("Enter Name Of Inspector")

    Dim counter As Integer

    Dim endOfTable
    endOfTable = 130

    Dim witnessSum As Integer: witnessSum = 0 'number witness by CCI
    Dim ICbyCrew As Integer: ICbyCrew = 0 'number done by crew

    Dim columnLetter As Integer: columnLetter = 11 'K

    For counter = 5 To endOfTable
        If StrComp(Cells(counter, columnLetter), personName) = 0 And _
            IsNumeric(Cells(counter, columnLetter - 1)) = True Then

            witnessSum = (witnessSum + Cells(counter, columnLetter - 1).Value)
            ICbyCrew = (ICbyCrew + Cells(counter, 4).Value)
        End If
    Next counter    

    For counter = 150 To 160 Step 1
        If Cells(counter, "E").Value = personName Then
            Cells(counter, "F").Value = ICbyCrew
            Cells(counter, "G").Value = witnessSum
            Cells(counter, "H").Value = (witnessSum / ICbyCrew)* 100 'This line is highlighted when I run the debugger'

            Exit For
        End If
    Next counter
End Sub    

Sub Inspector()

    Dim Inspector As String
    Dim Inspection As Integer: Inspection = 0
    Dim Witness As Integer: Witness = 0

    For x = 155 To 158      
        Inspector = Cells(x, "E")
        If Inspector = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

        For y = 5 To 120
            If (StrComp(Inspector, Cells(y, "K")) = 0) And (IsNumeric(Cells(y, "D")) = True) And (IsNumeric(Cells(y, "J")) = True) Then
                Inspection = Inspection + Cells(y, "D")
                Witness = Witness + Cells(y, "J")
            End If                
        Next y

    Cells(x, "F") = Inspection
    Cells(x, "G") = Witness
    Cells(x, "H") = (Witness / Inspection) * 100

    Inspection = 0
    Witness = 0        
    Next x    
End Sub
```

Comment: At what line do you get the error?

Comment: `x` and `y` are completely undefined. Its best practice to use option explicit and define variable types explicitly.

Comment: "Cells(counter, "H").Value = (witnessSum / ICbyCrew) 100" --Line 34

Comment: What is **Tally Inspector**?

Comment: Tally Inspector is the Macro I run to sum up the days the inspector worked in that week. It is also used to calculate the number of days he provided oversight to other foreman. All of this is then placed in a table that I made.

Comment: Is the variable `ICbyCrew` by chance equal to zero?

Comment: It could be . ICbyCrew is inspection completed by crew.

Comment: What result do you want the answer to be if `witnessSum` is (for instance) `5` and `ICbyCrew` is `0`?  What about when `witnessSum` is `0` and `ICbyCrew` is `0`?

Answer (score 2):

Redefine your `Integer` as `Long`. You're probably running over the 32,767 number limit of `Integer`.

Comment: *you're probably running over the 32,767 number limit of integer* - the code actual sets hard beginning and end points to all define variables (x and y, however are not defined anywhere!)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Hey Scott, read your comment yesterday but wasn't quite sure what you meant - Care to elaborate?

Comment: For example, in the line: `For counter = 5 To endOfTable` user sets `endOfTable` to a defined value of 130 which integer will handle. Other places this happens as well where `counter` is used in a loop.

Comment: Ahhh I see. To be honest, I hardly even looked at the code... I just saw that there were integers defined here and there, and with the overflow error I assumed that one of them needed to be a long. Thanks for clearing that up-

Answer (score 0):

Change your highlighted code from:

```
Cells(counter, "H").Value = (witnessSum / ICbyCrew) 100
```

to:

```
Cells(counter, "H").Value = (witnessSum / ICbyCrew) / 100
```

or to:

```
Cells(counter, "H") = witnessSum / ICbyCrew & 100
```

or to:

```
Cells(counter, "H") = witnessSum / ICbyCrew & " " &100
```

Comment: Cells(counter, "H").Value = (witnessSum / ICbyCrew) * 100

Comment: @Adeeb - what exactly should be staying in this cell?

Comment: Its just a column in my spreadsheet which calculates the percentage.